# Cross compiling opencv for rpi on fedora using eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

im still new to the Raspberry pi/linux platform and im seeking help for my project. Im trying to make a c++ program on fedora using eclipse with opencv for my raspberry pi 2 model B. I dont need help cross compiling as i can already do it with a program without opencv. What do I need to do to make this work with opencv? I already did alot of research online but most of the tutorial I found were on ubuntu instead of fedora or they used cmake instead of eclipse and I couldn't go into it without knowing if it would work or not. So if any of you could give me a bit of help i would really appreciate it.